# Codeigniter : Retriving data between two dates from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can I retrieve data from the database by querying records between two dates using codeigniter?

Here is my code :

```
   function date_employee_details($id,$fdate,$sdate)
   {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('user_id',$id);
    $this->db->where('dates >=',$fdate);
    $this->db->where('dates <=',$sdate);
    return $this->db->get('attendance');
    }
```

but i got an error :

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: fdate
Filename: models/admin.php
Line Number: 726
```

thanks

Comment: echo $fdate at the top of query and check what it return.

Comment: `$fdata` -> `$fdate`

Comment: ya i saw that.it`s return date. which date choose by user

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133/3933332